# Unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh"

Tags: docker, npm

***runc run failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm install --production @contrast/agent]: exit code: 1***

I've encountered error above when running docker build script in cmd.
FYI, my docker file included "RUN npm install ..."

[Here is my Dockerfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJ6Ga.png)

[and Here is the error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnO8C.png)

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your docker file to the question and any log output

Comment: @iain-shelvington, i've added it into my post.

Comment: The base image that you use does not have `npm` available/installed, can you use a different image?

Comment: may i know from where you checked that the base image does not have npm available/installed?

Comment: Here https://github.com/juice-shop/juice-shop/blob/master/Dockerfile#L15, the base image uses distroless/nodejs as a base image and that image removes most non-essential packages/tools https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless

Comment: oic, is there any other way to resolve this? so far i don't have different image from juice-shop...

Comment: There is an example of how to use the distroless image and also install packages here https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/examples/nodejs/Dockerfile. Using something similar with your base image as the last `FROM` may work

Comment: Sorry, I still can't get it. Can show me how I can exactly apply the changes as you suggested?

Comment: You don't seem to have actually included the Dockerfile in your question.  Can you [edit] the question to replace the image links with the actual text of the file(s)?

Comment: @David, The image is my docker file.